# Where in the server install does it mount /cdrom?

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, iso

If I try to boot the server installer iso as a CD - whether burnt directly to a CD, mounted in a virtual machine like an optical drive, or expanded onto a USB/SD - it works great.

If I try to grub loopback mount the iso and load the kernel and initrd from there, lots of things fall apart.

Apparently, the install process expects an actual cdrom to be at `/dev/sr0` that it then can mount at `/cdrom`, following which everything works.

I opened up `/boot/initrd.gz` from the iso to try and understand where and how it mounts the cd, so I can understand how to work around the limitation.

Where does it mount it? And is there a way to pass a kernel option via grub - or use some other grub method - to have it work correctly?

E.g. the desktop iso uses casper boot which supports `iso-scan/filename` and does the right thing. But not server (which, ironically, is the place least likely to have somewhere to put a CD....)